# Wordpress - A Loading or Splash Screen while wordpress load

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a shared web hosting. It's ok, but it takes about 10 seconds to load wordpress first time, if not used for some time.

The Wordpress is installed in root folder.

I tried to put a html (loading information) with Jquery to redirect to index.php, while the worpress 'wake', but it causes a loop.

I was thinking in change the folder installation of wordpres but I am afraid to stop the website and have difficulties to solve...

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>PLAPI</title>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.plapi.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/LoguinhoPlapi2.png">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="description" content="PLAPI - Plataforma de Aprendizagem Professora Isaura">
 <meta name="keywords" content="educação, conteúdo didático" />
 <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.plapi.com.br" />
 <meta property="og:keywords" content="Escola, professor, fundamentdal, ensino básico" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="PLAPI é uma plataforma de conteúdo e consultoria educacional" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="company" /> 
 <meta name="author" content="PLAPI">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="PLAPI - Plataforma de Aprendizagem Professora Isaura"/> 
 <meta name="description" content="PLAPI é uma plataforma de conteúdo e consultoria educacional">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <meta name="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
 var url = "https://www.plapi.com.br/index.php"; 
 $(location).attr('href',url); }); 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<style>
.loadercp2 {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: url('https://www.rnconstrutorabe.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/straight-loader.gif');
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
}
 
.divmaior {
 width: 200px;
 height: 280px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -160px;
 margin-left: -120px;
 //background-color: yellow;
}
</style>

<div class="divmaior" align="center"> <img src="https://www.plapi.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/cropped-LogoPlapi-1.png" style="width:160px; height="80px;"/>
 <div class="loadercp2" align="center"><span class="djr08rem"></span></div>
 <br><br><br><br><br>
 Carregando...
<div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

When I put this index.html, causes a Looping. So I renamed the index.html to indexok.html... http://plapi.com.br/indexok.html

What Can I do without change the folder installation of wordpress?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your htaccess code?

Comment: <IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg “access 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/jpeg “access 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/gif “access 1 year”
ExpiresByType image/png “access 1 year”
ExpiresByType text/css “access 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/pdf “access 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash “access 1 month”
ExpiresByType image/x-icon “access 1 year”
ExpiresDefault “access 2 days”
</IfModule>